# How to yield nested items populated from multiple pages / multipled parsers only once in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

New to scrapy here and trying to figure out how to yield only once the item once it's finished populating.

Trying to scrape a site that publishes swimmer times which is built in a way that the pages are structured like this:

> Swimmer search page -> Swimmer page with list of swim styles -> Style page with all the times for that style

I am using a nested set of items

> Swimmer -> [Styles] -> [Times]

To output a single json dict per every Swimmer, containing all the styles s/he swam and all the times done within each style.

I have the issue that this code yields the same item over and over again rather than just once (as I would want and expect), so creating a lot of waste.

```
import scrapy
from tempusopen.settings import swimmers
from tempusopen.items import Swimmer, Time, Style
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader


class BaseUrl(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()


class RecordsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'records_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.tempusopen.fi']

    def start_requests(self):
        base_url = ('https://www.tempusopen.fi/index.php?r=swimmer/index&Swimmer[first_name]={firstname}&'
                    'Swimmer[last_name]={lastname}&Swimmer[searchChoice]=1&Swimmer[swimmer_club]={team}&'
                    'Swimmer[class]=1&Swimmer[is_active]=1')
        urls = [base_url.format_map(x) for x in swimmers]

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        swimmer_url = response.xpath('//table//tbody/tr/td/a[@class="view"]/@href').get()
        swimmer = Swimmer()
        return response.follow(swimmer_url, callback=self.parse_records, meta={'swimmer': swimmer})

    def parse_records(self, response):
        distances = response.xpath('//table//tbody/tr/td/a[@class="view"]/@href').extract()
        swimmer_data = response.xpath("//div[@class='container main']//"
                                      "div[@class='sixteen columns']//text()").extract()
        swimmer = response.meta['swimmer']
        swimmer['id'] = response.url.split('=')[-1]
        swimmer['name'] = swimmer_data[1]
        swimmer['team'] = swimmer_data[5].strip('\n').split(',')[0].split(':')[1].strip()
        swimmer['status'] = swimmer_data[5].split(',')[1:]
        swimmer_data = response.xpath("//div[@class='container main']//"
                                      "div[@class='clearfix']//div[@class='six columns']"
                                      "//text()").extract()
        swimmer['born'] = swimmer_data[2].strip('\n')
        swimmer['license'] = swimmer_data[4].strip('\n')
        for url in distances:
            yield response.follow(url, callback=self.parse_distances, meta={'swimmer': swimmer})

    def parse_distances(self, response):
        swimmer = response.meta['swimmer']
        style = Style()
        try:
            swimmer['styles']
        except:
            swimmer['styles'] = []
        distance = response.xpath('//div[@class="container main"]//p/text()').extract_first()
        distance = distance.strip().split('\n')[1]
        style['name'] = distance
        try:
            style['times']
        except:
            style['times'] = []
        swimmer['styles'].append(style)
        table_rows = response.xpath("//table//tbody/tr")
        for tr in table_rows:
            t = Time()
            t['time'] = tr.xpath("./td[1]/text()").extract_first().strip("\n\xa0")
            t['date'] = tr.xpath("./td[4]/text()").extract_first()
            t['competition'] = tr.xpath("./td[5]/text()").extract_first()
            style['times'].append(t)
        return swimmer
```

I suppose the issue is to use `yield` and `return` in the "right" way but I can't figure out the right solution.

I tried with only `yield` and I can see the json dict of each swimmer slowly populating.
I tried with only one last `return swimmer` at the end and everywhere `yield` but that just gave me the same json dict per each swimmer repeated endlessly...

The wanted behavior would be that the code would output one single json dict per each swimmer I search for in `start_urls` list (not the gazillions I am getting now).

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Ps. you can pull the code [here](https://github.com/stezz/tempusopen/tree/708f4f1e265121bae0820907800b442119f5cfcf)

As an example of `swimmers` dict you can use this one:

```
swimmers = [
# Add here the list of swimmers you are interested in scraping
{'firstname': 'Lenni', 'lastname': 'Parpola', 'team': ''},
{'firstname': 'Tommi', 'lastname': 'Kangas', 'team': ''},
]
```

Comment: Can you also share code of `tempusopen.settings` and `tempusopen.items`, so I can reproduce it?

Comment: thanks for taking interest @RomanFerenets, I added the link to github and an example of swimmers dict

Answer (score 1):

You have two alternatives:

1. Use [Scrapy Inline Requests](https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-inline-requests) to implement `parse_distance`
2. Don't change anything in your code but create a custom `pipelines.py` and work (add new dictionary details) with each swimmer in `process_item` section. You'll be able to `yield` all results at the end of your spider.

Comment: Thanks @gangabass, among the 2 it feels like the pipelines option is the more canonical way. I guess I just didn’t get to that part of the tutorial  I will give it a try and let’s see how that goes

Comment: uhm... @gangabass if I change nothing in my code but just add a JsonItemExporter() pipeline it seems I get exactly the same result. Can you explain better what you mean by 
>  work (add new dictionary details) with each swimmer in process_item section
?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out, mostly thanks to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45496764/creating-scrapy-array-of-items-with-multiple-parse).

Because of the way how scrapy works rather than using a normal 'for' loop in the `parse_records` parser, we need to go through each URL one by one and exhaust the urls in `distances` before returning a `swimmer` item back (if we don't do that we will return the same swimmer item multiple times rather than once per swimmer).

This is achieved by popping the first url and passing the distances_urls through the next level and checking that we are really done with this swimmer before firing a 'return' (in the next level of parsing, which is `parse_distances`).

Once in there we manually go to the next style by popping the url out of the distances_url list and recursively calling this parse_distances method until we exhaust the distances urls list and finally, if we really are done with the styles for this `swimmer`, we return a swimmer item. Exactly once per every swimmer.

For reference you can see the whole thing in action [on github](https://github.com/stezz/tempusopen/blob/b98b230d538768c31838be36b45c4610f31f7353/tempusopen/spiders/records_spider.py)

Comment: Note: if anyone knows of a better way of doing this (maybe @gangabass using the method you refer to, which I didn't get to work?) please comment, I believe that this is a problem that not only I am facing :)